# Can I reuse a function inside the same function?

Tags: javascript

Just a quick question: Can I call the same function within a function?

```js
function rIN() {
    randomImgNumber = (Math.round(imgNumber * Math.random())) - 1;
    if (randomImgNumber === "undefined") {
        rIN();
    }
    return imgArray[randomImgNumber];
}
```

If not, is there another way I can redo the same function inside a function?

I'm sorry if this is a bad question, I am a beginner in coding.

Comment: I believe you can :). That's called recursion :). Do some research on that

Comment: have you tried and what is happening?

Comment: Sure.  It's called recursion.  Just make sure you are going to hit your condition at some point otherwise you'll get a stack overflow!

Comment: You can indeed, and it is called recursion. However, this code is not correct for several other unrelated or semilrelated reasons.

Comment: just `function rIN() {
  return imgArray[Math.floor(imgArray.length * Math.random())];
}`

Comment: You can read more aboute recursion in JavaScript [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions#Recursion)

Comment: @Shadow - when do you expect `randomImgNumber === "undefined"` evaluate to `true`?

Comment: `randomImgNumber` will be a number, given `imgNumber` is a numerical value... so your condition `randomImgNumber === "undefined"` will never be true

Comment: Ah, okay. Thanks all for your replies; I got it to work. :)